# Opencart default language doesn't work

Tags: browser, opencart

I have OpenCart multi language store with Arabic and English, I set the default language to be Arabic, it works well for all devices except on Samsung where it will show the browser's language as a default language. I would like a a way to force the default language for my store to be Arabic.

my Website URL is : Qadooa.com

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for second language packs for opencart.

bugissue:

- not showing icons (like: myaccount, language, etc..)
- not putting your default language really to default on live webshops!

solution:
.htaccess.TXT (save this document as .htaccess (no TXT! save with *all documents selected)

then add the following text after line 31 (install Notepad++ to see line numbers):

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```